# UITapGestureRecognizer not working - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I see that there are a ton of these questions, and I think I'm following the accepted Swift 3 methodology, but I'm still getting nothing.  I can see that the UITapGestureRecognizer has been attached.  Here's my code:

```
let tileClick = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameManagement.initiateTileClick(_:)))
newView.addGestureRecognizer(tileClick)
newView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

func initiateTileClick(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("initiate tile click")
}
```

A few things to note:

1) The view that I'm attaching the gesture recognizer to has a two views and a label within it that each cover the entire frame of the view, however, I tried attaching the recognizer to the label, which is the topmost child item and it still doesn't work.

2) Both the function that adds the recognizer and the function that is called on the tap are contained in an NSObject file.  I have a variety of interconnected functions that I want to be able to call from multiple view controllers and would prefer to keep this in the separate NSObject file.  The process worked when I had everything in a UIViewController file and stopped working when I moved the functions to the NSObject file.

3) I've tried changing `GameManagement.initiateTileClick` to `self.initiateTileClick` or just `initiateTileClick` and none of those worked.

Comment: You are not showing enough code. How do we even known that `newView` ever gets into the interface? How do we know that this code runs (you say you moved everything into an NSObject, but where does it live and what triggers your code)?

Comment: Your first point makes it sound like you are trying to attach the same gesture `tileClick` to *both* the view `newView` *and* this subview that is a UILabel. If so, that won't work. One "attachment" per defined gesture.

Answer (score 6):

If you are putting your views inside `NSObject` subclass then these `views` will lose their behaviors for `UIResponder` which manages the UI interactions as I am not able to see how you are adding these views to interface.

As you said, it was working inside `ViewController` because it manages view hierarchy and responder chain.

The solution would be to write `extensions` to separate code or better abstractions.

```
extension YourViewController {

   newView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameManagement.initiateTileClick(_:))))
   newView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

   func initiateTileClick(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      print("initiate tile click")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Giving you an idea how the tap recogniser works.

Firstly add Tap gesture recogniser to your view controller. You have to put the object here as shown in the image.

[image: Drop your tap gesture object here]

Then control+drag the tap gesture object to your view and select delegate.

Then control+drag the recogniser to your swift file and action will be like this.

```
@IBAction func tapGesture(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

}
```

Now you must have seen when you give some input to a text field, the keyboard appears. But if you press outside the text field, that is anywhere in the view, the keyboard hides. This is because of the tap gesture recogniser.

Consider you have a text field such that if you click in that text field, keyboard is appeared. But when you tap outside the textfield, the keyboard must hide.

Add this delegate

```
UITextFieldDelegate
```

Implement this:

```
@IBOutlet var phoneText: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    exampleText.delegate = self
}

@IBAction func tapGesture(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    exampleText.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously,this function is instance method.

```
func initiateTileClick(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("initiate tile click")
}
```

-

```
UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(GameManagement.initiateTileClick(_:)))
```

but this`GameManagement.initiateTileClick(_:)` looks like a class is calling a class method!The target should be the caller of method.`self` can't call `GameManagement.initiateTileClick(_:)`.